# Seeking examples of Open Data in formal journalism Standards & Practices

Tags: journalism

As an arbitrary example, note [this page](http://www.cbc.radio-canada.ca/en/reporting-to-canadians/acts-and-policies/programming/journalism/investigative-journalism/) is CBC (Canadian Broadcasting Corporation) Radio's Standards & Practices on Investigative Journalism. Note the section on Data Journalism (which is silent on Open Data).

I'm looking for a similar document online for any major media outlet that clearly addresses Open Data in the contemporary sense.

Perhaps the example states something like: *"When Open Data is used relating to a story, we provide a link to the data and the license, in accordance with the stated licensing terms of the provider"*. (I'm not a journalist but hopefully readers will get the idea. I'm coming at this from the Open Data perspective.)

Ideally, it might even say *"We ask about Open Data as a part of normal protocol. If data is provided, but not as Open Data, we disclose that the story contains data which is not Open Data"*.

Comment: open news almost does this. i'd argue open technologies includes data but i know that is not what you want https://source.opennews.org/

Comment: google news lab certainly shares their data. but again not sure if its 100% what you seek. via https://twitter.com/smfrogers/status/1016988535285583872 and https://github.com/GoogleTrends/data

Answer (score 2):

As you say, many organisations policies are silent on this: the only one I can find is the [About page of the ProPublica Data Store](https://www.propublica.org/datastore/about). There are, however some less-formal documents that might be useful.

[Simon Rogers](https://simonrogers.net/about/), then data editor at The Guardian (now doing the same at Google), wrote [an article on the Guardian's approach to open data in journalism](https://www.theguardian.com/news/datablog/2012/sep/20/open-data-journalism) in 2012. The Reuters Institute did a [paper on the practice of open data journalism](https://reutersinstitute.politics.ox.ac.uk/our-research/does-open-data-need-journalism) in 2015.

You probably already know that Five Thirty Eight [publishes data for many of its articles on GitHub](https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/), so they clearly have a policy on this even if it isn't published anywhere. Source has [an article summarising the open-data practices of the big data-journalism outfits](https://source.opennews.org/articles/what-open-really-means-538-vox-and-upshot/) including Vox, The Upshot etc. but it's a bit dated now (from 2014).

One useful thing might be to ask people (e.g. on Twitter) from data journalism publications whether they're happy to share any policies they have?